# ValueError: could not convert string to float: matrix file

Tags: python-3.x, string, file, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Gretings i have a file matrix.txt, with the following matrix 3x3 dtype float32...

-----------------matrix.txt------------

```
[[ 2.94795074e+00  3.15288849e-02 -8.67170450e+02]
 [-2.21123258e-17  2.94877180e+00 -5.95651904e+02]
 [ 1.49601560e-04  1.52843706e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
```

---

```
p_homo = np.array([[1], [1], [1]])    
file = open('matrix.txt', 'r')
matrix_file_l =list()
matrix_file_l = file.read()
matrix_file = np.array(matrix_file_l,  dtype="float32")

def mult_matrix(matrix1, matrix2):
    matrixx = np.empty([len(matrix1), len(matrix2[0])])
    for i in range(len(matrix1)):
        for j in range(len(matrix2[0])):
            for k in range(len(matrix2)):
                matrixx[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]
    return matrixx

matrix = mult_matrix(matrix_file, p_homo)
```

matrix_file is a string and i can not covert to a float32 i try casting in many ways

```
matrix_file = np.array(matrix_file_l,  dtype="float32")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[-5.62093010e+01...
```

Comment: It would be easier to read that file if it didn't include the brackets.  Just the numbers, equal number of columns for each row, with some well defined delimiter (space or comma).  The so called `csv` format.

Comment: yes it is true but i need the brackets for later multiply the matrix @hpaulj..  thanks

Comment: You don't need the brackets in the text file.  Technically the brackets aren't part of the array either - they are just part of the array's pretty display format.  `csv` readers like `np.genfromtxt` create an array from the csv file.

Comment: if for some good reason I cannot think of the textfile already comes with the brackets, try using `eval`: `matrix_file = np.array(eval(matrix_file_l))`. FYI also numpy has functions for matrix multiplications (`np.matmul`, `np.dot`)

Comment: @Mstaino i try with `eval:` but the same error.. `matrix_file = np.array(matrix_file_l, dtype="float32")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[ 1.82278459e+00  1.91872062e-02 -8.78831607e+02]\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me... I use numpy `np.save` and `np.load` instead files `file = open('matrix.txt', 'w')` `file.write(matrix)` `matrix_value = file.read()` to save my matrix in matrix.npy after that was easy make the operation because numpy saves the values as a numpy.ndarray not as strings
....

---------------  script1  ------------------

...

```
np.save('matrix', matrix_value)
```

...

----------  script2  ---------------

```
p_homo = np.array([[1], [1], [1]])    
a= np.load('matrix.npy')
```

...

```
matrix = mult_matrix(a, p_homo)
```